# Component render not all content

Tags: reactjs, web3js

I trying to make component which will return all information from Smart Contract (web3 library) and return that. When I go to page which returning that component content - I didn't see my content from Smart Contract. It will be returning with a little bit delay and if I going in same page twice then I saw my content.

```
export default class MyUsers extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            tokens: [],
            users: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var owner = this.props.match.params.username;
        var that = this;

        window.smartContract.methods.tokensOfOwner(owner).call().then(function (tokens) {
            tokens.map((data, idx) => {
                that.state.tokens.push(data);

                // Get hero data
                window.smartContract.methods.getUsers(data).call().then(function (userData) {

                    userData.userid = data;
                    that.state.users.push([userData]);
                });
                return true;
            });
        });

    }

    renderUsers() {
        const that = this;
        const getUsersInformation = this.state.users.map((data, idx) => {
            console.log(data);
            var birthTime = new Date(parseInt(data[0].birthTime) * 1000);
            return (
                <div className="col-md-4" key={idx.toString()}>

                    <Card>
                        <CardBody>
                            <CardTitle className="mb-0">
                                <h4 className="mb-0">User No. <strong>{ data[0].userid }</strong></h4>
                            </CardTitle>
                            <CardSubtitle>
                                <small>ID No. <strong>{ data[0].id }</strong></small>
                            </CardSubtitle>
                            <hr />
                            <Table>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td className="font-weight-bold">Birthdate:</td>
                                        <td>{ birthTime.getFullYear() }-0{ birthTime.getMonth() + 1 }-0{ birthTime.getDay() + 1 }</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </Table>
                        </CardBody>
                    </Card>
                </div>
            );
        });
        return getUsersInformation;
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <Card>
                <CardBody>
                    <CardTitle>
                        <h3>My Users</h3>
                    </CardTitle>
                    <hr />
                    <div className="row">
                        {this.renderUsers()}
                    </div>
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: 1rst use setState to manipulate state in react, and 2. check if data is there, for example `this.state.users.length>0 && this.state.users.map(...)` because in initial moment when you reneder your array is empty. And react initialize components i some order, constructor>render>componentDidMount>render. That's why you need to check if data has been loaded

Answer (score 0):

Use `setState` instead of pushing element to array:

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

```
componentDidMount() {
    var owner = this.props.match.params.username;
    //var that = this;

    window.smartContract.methods.tokensOfOwner(owner).call().then(tokens => {
        tokens.map((data, idx) => {
            //that.state.tokens.push(data);
            this.setState({tokens: [...this.state.tokens, data]})

            // Get hero data
            window.smartContract.methods.getUsers(data).call().then(userData => {

                userData.userid = data;
                //that.state.users.push([userData]);
                this.setState({users: [...this.state.users, userData]})
            });
            return true;
        });
    });

}
```

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state